# Ghostscript conversion of a .ps file into a .png file give an empty image (entirely black)

Tags: python, subprocess, ghostscript

I runned the following instruction in order to convert a postscript file into a .png file (I have obtained this postscript file by using the postscript method on a canvas). The instruction is:

```
subprocess.run(' "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin/gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile="C:/Users/rid/Desktop/results/Sub-frame4.png" "C:/Users/rid/Desktop/codes rev 2/Sub-frame4.ps" ', shell=True)
```

The entire code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
import subprocess

class ScrolledFrame(tk.Frame):#written by furas

    def __init__(self, parent, vertical=True, horizontal=False):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # canvas for inner frame
        self._canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self._canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news') # changed

        # create right scrollbar and connect to canvas Y
        self._vertical_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self._canvas.yview)
        if vertical:
            self._vertical_bar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')
        self._canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=self._vertical_bar.set)

        # create bottom scrollbar and connect to canvas X
        self._horizontal_bar = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self._canvas.xview)
        if horizontal:
            self._horizontal_bar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
        self._canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self._horizontal_bar.set)

       # inner frame for widgets
        self.inner = tk.Frame(self._canvas)
        self._window = self._canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.inner, anchor='nw')

       # autoresize inner frame
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1) # changed

       # resize when configure changed
        self.inner.bind('<Configure>', self.resize)

       # resize inner frame to canvas size
        self.resize_width = False
        self.resize_height = False
        self._canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.inner_resize)

    def resize(self, event=None): 
        self._canvas.configure(scrollregion=self._canvas.bbox('all'))

    def inner_resize(self, event):
        # resize inner frame to canvas size
        if self.resize_width:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, width=event.width)
        if self.resize_height:
            self._canvas.itemconfig(self._window, height=event.height)

Input = ([[1, 2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8]]) #exemple

color_1 = "#d1f3cd"
color_2 = "#b3ecac"
color_3 = "#81df77"
color_4 = "#53d345"
color_5 = "#36ae29"
nombre_nuances = 5

def get_max(my_list):
    m = None
    for item in my_list:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            item = get_max(item)
        if not m or m < item:
            m = item
    return m
my_window= tk.Tk()
sf = ScrolledFrame(my_window, True, True)
sf.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

def grid_function(tableau2D, sf):    
    rows = len(tableau2D)
    cols = len(list(zip(*tableau2D)))
    maximum = get_max(tableau2D)
    tranche_couleur_1 = maximum/nombre_nuances
    tranche_couleur_2 = tranche_couleur_1*2
    tranche_couleur_3 = tranche_couleur_1*3
    tranche_couleur_4 = tranche_couleur_1*4       
    for x in range(0, rows):
        for y in range(0, cols):
            current_element = tableau2D[x][y]
            if current_element<=tranche_couleur_1:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_1)
            elif current_element>tranche_couleur_1 and current_element<=tranche_couleur_2:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_2)
            elif current_element>tranche_couleur_2 and current_element<=tranche_couleur_3:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_3)
            elif current_element>tranche_couleur_3 and current_element<=tranche_couleur_4:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_4)
            elif current_element>tranche_couleur_4:
                label=tk.Label (sf.inner, width="20", height="5", bg=color_5)

            label.grid (row=x,column=y)

grid_function(Input, sf)

input_name="Sub-frame"+str(4)+".ps"
output_name="Sub-frame"+str(4)+".png"
ps=sf._canvas.postscript(file=input_name, colormode='color')
subprocess.run(' "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin/gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile="C:/Users/rid/Desktop/results/Sub-frame4.png" "C:/Users/rid/Desktop/codes rev 2/Sub-frame4.ps" ', shell=True)
my_window.mainloop()
```

The .png file is created in the right folder, but when I open it, there is no image, it is entirely black and I don't know why. Can you tell me what the point is?

Comment: Can you provide the postscript file? Have you checked whether other tools backending into or using postscript work with it correctly?

Comment: If the same problem happens when you run `gswin64c` from the command line by hand without Python involved at all, then this isn't a Python question in any meaningful way.

Comment: @Charles Duffy, I edited my post by adding the code used to create the canvas and to convert it in a postscript file. I didn't find another way to provide the postscript file.

Comment: If you are passing the PostScript to Ghostscript, then there must, somewhere, be a PostScript file being generated. Going by your command line it will be the file "C;/Users/rid/Desktop/codes rev 2/Sub-frame4.ps". You need to put that file somewhere public. I see you've finally managed to resolve your other problems, though I don't think you;ve actually said what your problems were, which is unfortunate as the answer won't be available for other people with the same or similar problems. Oh, you should upgrade your version of Ghostscript too, that's an old version.

Comment: @KenS, I will edit my other post to add what the problems were (file paths must be into quotes and I have to put the full path of gswin64c.exe). I don't understand when you said:"You need to put that file somewhere public". Do you think that is the reason why the .png file is entirely black?

Comment: I put the folder "codes rev 2" in "C:\Users\Public", and change the instruction into: subprocess.run(' "C:/Program Files/gs/gs9.22/bin/gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -sOutputFile="C:/Users/Public/final results/Sub-frame4.png" "C:/Users/Public/codes rev 2/Sub-frame4.ps" ', shell=True), but I still get a .png file without an image (it is entirely black).

Comment: I mean that you need to create the PostScript program (C:/Users/Public/codes rev 2/Sub-frame4.ps) then take that file, place that file somewher public so we can look at it. I doubt the problem is Ghostcript, its more likely that the output is black because that's what the PostScript program is coded to do.

Comment: @KenS, I created the postscript file and put it in my google drive. The link is:https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zWoPnfLiymhK-vA07qb2tXfLOAqcsxAS

Comment: I can't see how you would get a **black** output image, for me its white, and that's because the PostScript program makes no marks on the page. As I've said I don't speak Pythion, so I'm not sure what to exepct, but it looks to me like your problem is not with Ghostscript, its a problem generating the PostScript file from the canvas. I can't help you with that I'm afraid. FWIW the PostScript program claims to be an EPS file, but it isn't a legal EPS, that sort of thing makes me doubt the quality of the generating application.